# HDMI Male to DVI-D Dual link support 144hz with Radeon R9 Nano?

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, dvi

I have a Benq XL2411 144hz monitor where ONLY the DVI-D Dual link input supports 144hz and Radeon R9 Nano... I can't seem to find a DisplayPort To Dvi-D Dual link adaptor or cable in my country so i am forced to go HDMI because the R9 Nano doesn't have DVI-D outputs.... The Radeon R9 Nano has 1 HDMI 1.4 output... So my questions is will HDMI 1.4 to DVI-D dual link adaptor work for 144hz 1920x1080 the adaptor i am looking to buy is this:
https://www.hdcabling.co.za/male-hdmi-to-dvi-d-female-dual-link-adapter-gold-plated-connectors-p-753.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDMI is always single-link. Like DisplayPort, it would require active conversion to Dual-Link DVI.

You need to get an active converter. You probably won’t be able to find one that supports 144 Hz, though.

You’re better off just returning the monitor and getting one that supports DisplayPort.

Comment: Thanks... but yeah im stuck now because my monitor is 3years old xD i might just sell my monitor and get a new one